# Is there a short an beautiful way to delete empty Lists of an empty List in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I got a List of List of Integers. While some nested Lists contain Integers, some do not.

```
Dim innerList1 As New List(Of Integer)
Dim innerList2 As New List(Of Integer)
Dim innerList3 As New List(Of Integer)
Dim outerList As New List(Of List(Of Integer))

innerList1.add(1)
innerList1.add(2)
innerList3.add(25)

outerList.add(innerList1)
outerList.add(innerList2)
outerList.add(innerList3)
```

The Output could look like this:

*outerList:*

*innerList1:* 1 2

*innerList2:*

*innerList3:* 25

Now I want to delete the empty innerList with following code:

```
For i = 0 to outerList.Count() - 1
    If (outerList(i).Count() = 0) Then
        outerList.remove(outerList(i))
    End If
Next
```

The problem is, that the index will be out of Range after some Iterations once an innerList is deleted.

I tried also while-statements and do loops. But nothing worked.

I would be very thankful, if someone could help me :)

Comment: Side note: Use `Count`, not `Count()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short and beautiful way is to use the `RemoveAll` method, which will remove all items that satisfy specific criteria:

```vb
outerList.RemoveAll(Function(l) l.Count = 0)
```

Notice that this is using the `Count` property of the `List` as well, not the `Enumerable.Count` extension method. By adding parentheses as you did, you are calling that extension method. Don't do that when you know what type the list is and that it has a dedicated property, e.g. `Count` here or `Length` for an array.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found an awnser.
I just looped through my List in reversed direction, so the Index will never be out of range.

Answer (score 1):

Or with LINQ:

```
outerList = outerList.Where(Function(x) x.Count > 0).ToList()
```

(Note, this replaces the outerList with a new one. If you're in a sub/function where outerList has been passed ByVal (and this is not a recommendation to use ByRef) then the calling sub won't see the change)